# Draw a line with transition in javafx

Tags: javafx, line, transition

I'm making a Tic Tac Toe game in JavaFX and I want to draw a line on win using transition. I've searched on youtube, StackOverflow, etc. but can't find a solution. 
This is the code of the drawline function

```
private void drawLine()
    {
        List<Integer> winningMoves;
        if (getTurn() == player1) {
            winningMoves = Result.getPlayer1moves();
        } else {
            winningMoves = Result.getPlayer2moves();
        }
        Collections.sort(winningMoves);
        int startX = 35, startY = 35, endX = 35, endY = 35;
        switch (winningMoves.get(0)) {
            case 1:
                startX += 50 + 15;
                startY += 50 + 15 + 15;
                switch (winningMoves.get(2)) {
                    case 3:
                        endX += 50 + 15 + 70 + 30 + 70 + 30;
                        endY += 50 + 15 + 15;
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        endX += 50 + 15;
                        endY += 50 + 15 + 15 + 70 + 30 + 70 + 30;
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        endX += 50 + 15 + 70 + 30 + 70 + 30;
                        endY += 50 + 15 + 15 + 70 + 30 + 70 + 30;
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                startX += 50 + 15 + 70 + 30;
                startY += 50 + 15 + 15;
                endX += 50 + 15 + 70 + 30;
                endY += 50 + 15 + 70 + 30 + 70 + 30 + 15;
                break;
            case 3:
                startX += 50 + 15 + 70 + 30 + 70 + 30;
                startY += 50 + 15 + 15;
                switch (winningMoves.get(2)) {
                    case 7:
                        endX += 50 + 15;
                        endY += 50 + 15 + 15 + 70 + 30 + 70 + 30;
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        endX += 50 + 15 + 70 + 30 + 70 + 30;
                        endY += 50 + 15 + 15 + 70 + 30 + 70 + 30;
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                startX += 50 + 15;
                startY += 50 + 15 + 15 + 70 + 30 + 15;
                endX += 50 + 15 + 70 + 30 + 70 + 30;
                endY += 50 + 15 + 70 + 30 + 15;
                break;
            case 7:
                startX += 50 + 15;
                startY += 50 + 15 + 15 + 70 + 30 + 70 + 30;
                endX += 50 + 15 + 70 + 30 + 70 + 30;
                endY += 50 + 15 + 15 + 70 + 30 + 70 + 30;
                break;
        }
        line.setStartX(startX);
        line.setStartY(startY);
        line.setEndX(endX);
        line.setEndY(endY);
        line.setStroke(Color.AQUA);
    }
```

I want to draw this line with a transition
 [Full code of the game on GitHub](https://github.com/Nishith-Savla/Tic-Tac-Toe-Game-in-JavaFX/)

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do that with a transition (at least not without binnding). A `Timeline` animation would be much better suited anyways. (That is assuming the desired animation is transforming the line from a dot to the final line. Also it seems like you could replace the `switch` with `x = (50 + 15) + ((m-1) % 3) * (70+30); y = (50 + 15 + 15) + ((m-1) / 3) * (70 + 30);` for move `m`; (case 2 anr 4 in the outer `switch` for some reason use a y value that is of by 15, but in general this seems accurately determine the coordinates of the corresponding point.

Comment: Thank you so much for that equation, sir. It helped me make my code better and shorter